# Open a new window from a dataview in EXTJS MVC

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Am trying to open a new window in EXTJS MVC. This window is opened when an icon in a dataview is clicked. Am able to see the call to the window in firebug, but am just getting a blank screen in the application.
The code is as follows:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.test',
    initComponent: function () {

        var msgTxt = GENHTML.msgTxtOpen + LANG.ADDCOURSEF1 + GENHTML.msgTxtClose2

        var required = '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>';

        var test_form = {
            xtype: 'panel',
            itemId: 'TESTPANEL',
            width: 400

            cls: 'msg effect1',
            layout: 'form',
            border: false,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                //cls : 'winTitle',
                html: msgTxt,
                border: 0
            }, {
                xtype: 'form',
                itemId: 'TESTFORM',
                buttons: [{
                    text: LANG.BTSUBMIT,
                    iconCls: 'icon-submit-tb',
                    iconAlign: 'right',
                    cls: 'tip-btn',
                    id: 'BTGENSUBMIT',
                    action: 'buttonAction'
                }],
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        baseCls: 'x-plain',
                        bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px 0 5px 5px',
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            value: LANG.EDITCOURSEFL1
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                            value: '<div class = "spacer10"/>'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            itemId: 'title',
                            name: 'title',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            fieldLabel: LANG.CATALOGUEWINFL1,
                            afterLabelTextTpl: required,
                            vtypeText: LANG.GENVT

                        }]
                    }]
                }]

                var config = {
                    xtype: 'window',
                    title: 'Edit Courses',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    itemID: 'TESTWINDOW',
                    id: 'TESTWINDOW',
                    closable: true,
                    modal: true,
                    items: [test_form]
                }

                var holder = Ext.getCmp('center');
                holder.remove(0);
                holder.add(Ext.apply(config));

                this.callParent(arguments);
            }
```

Controller :

```
onTestViewSelectionChange: function (view, record, h, ind, evt) {

    var edit = evt.getTarget('a.icon-edit-32');
    if (edit != null) {

        var view = Ext.create('Campus.view.Test');
        view.show(record);
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether I have created the window properly, and whether I am invoking it properly. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your code:

First is the use of **[show](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-show)**. I think you have override it? I would choose `loadRecord()` and leave `show()` as it is.

```
var view = Ext.create('Campus.view.Test');
view.show(record);
```

Second is your call of `Ext.apply()` which does nothing here. You simply don't need it.

```
holder.add(Ext.apply(config));
```

So, placing some bit's of logic directly into your views and not all in the controllers is perfectly OK in your case I guess. But mind that I only know this small part of your app.

Third is that you will need to call `show()` on a window instance because they are not visible by default. But you can set the **[autoShow](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-autoShow)** property like `autoShow: true`

fourth is that it is a bad habbit to set the `id` prop by your. If possible don't do it and make use of the **[Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)**.

Comment: Thank you sra, it was the config option autoShow : true, that solved the problem:)